# how to create a customized form

Tags: symfony

I'm working in a project and I would like to create form and not using `form_widget`. I want to create my own form.

Here is my controller:

```
public function newAction()
{
    $entity = new Etudiant();
    $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

    return $this->render('MyAppRevBundle:Etudiant:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

And my html page is:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body -%}

<form action="{{ path('etudiant') }}" {{form_enctype(form)}} method="post" >

    <label for="username" class="col-md-2 control_label">Login :</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="Thaer"required="required" />
   <br>
       <input type="submit"/> 
       {{ form_rest(form) }}
</form>

<ul class="record_actions">
<li>
    <a href="{{ path('etudiant') }}">
       return
    </a>
</li>
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: For future reference: a *formulaire* is a *form* in English. (I'm French too)

Answer (score 0):

so i solved

so it should be

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body -%}

<form action="{{ path('etudiant') }}" {{form_enctype(form)}} method="post" >

  <table> 
 <tr>
    <td>Libelle: </td>
    <td>{{ form_widget(form.libelle)}}
 </tr>



 </table>

< input type="submit" />
 {{ form_rest(form) }}
</form> 



  <ul class="record_actions">
<li>
<a href="{{ path('etudiant') }}">
   return
</a>
</li> 
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is the solution? What is different from the code of your question?

Comment: I'm note sure , but when i tried the first code it doesn't work , the second code i used the form_widget and i can submit my form on the database